Maximum of the length of period of repeating decimals
I, along with another, have found a fact that the length $l$ of period of repeating decimal $\dfrac1b$ is always less than $b$. For example,
$\dfrac13=0.\overline{3}$, in which $1<3$; 
$\dfrac17=0.\overline{142857}$, in which $6<7$; 
$\dfrac{1}{17}=0.\overline{0588235294117647}$, in which $16<17$.
The fact is obvious, but I'd like to know how to prove it.

Hint: You want to find the minimum $k$ such that $10^k \equiv 1 \pmod{b'}$, where $\gcd (b', 10) = 1$ and $ b = b'*t$ with $ t \mid 10^s$.

How many possible remainders are there when $10^k$ is divided by $p$?

ok and now I've known how to prove it through Fermat Theorem.
